# Method Not Getting Called

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm working on Stanford's CS193p (Fall 2010) assignment #3.  I have the below code in a UIView subclass:

```
float scale = [self.delegate scaleForGraphView:self];
```

Breakpoints and NSLogs inside scaleForGraphView are never triggered, but NSLogs and breakpoints at the above line indicate that it is getting executed.  Can someone explain why I'm not seeing execution inside the scaleForGraphView method?

Comment: Wouldn't normally tag this one as homework, but you've explicitly stated that it's homework, so the tag it gets!  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put in:

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.delegate);
```

I'd be willing to bet that either:

1. It's the wrong kind of object
2. It's `nil`

Comment: My goodness this board is fast.  Yes, putting the NSLog statement you suggested revealed that self.delegate was nil.  I wouldn't have thought to do that without your suggestion, thank you.  Now to figure out why it is nil...

Comment: @Michael Mangold: When a method is mysteriously not doing something it seems like it should, that's strong evidence that you have a nil where you don't expect it, since nil just silently ignores everything you tell it.

Answer (score 1):

Without more code, that is hard to answer, but it looks as if self.delegate is nil.